# C# Await till object is in list, for controller

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await, controller

Hi i currently have a web api system where i send a command to a Machine at another location. Id like to wait for the response from the system to be available to send back to the requester. Currently when a request is made i generate a UUID and once data comes back from the other location it matches with that UUID and adds it to a response list. Is there any way i can await that a list contains x

If not is there any other way that i might be able to transfer this object from the very distant class and thread to the controller for the response to be sent back?

Code from webrequest

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Areas")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetArea(GetAreas getAreas)
    {
        OutScaleManager.LogRequest("Request to getAreas with ip: " + getAreas.IP + " i " + getAreas.startArea + " i " + getAreas.endArea);
        foreach (NoxApiService noxService in OutScaleManager.nUtil.connectedInstance)
        {
            if (noxService.param.IPAddress == getAreas.IP)
            {
                noxService.GetAreas(getAreas.startArea, getAreas.endArea);
                OutScaleManager.LogRequest("getAreas Sent, now moving to queue checks");
                string UUID = OutScaleManager.nRAR.NoxRequestHandler(getAreas, RequestType.GETAREAS);
                if (OutScaleManager.nRAR.GetAreasResponseSend)
                {
                    await OutScaleManager.nRAR.ResponseList.ContainsKey(UUID);
                }
                //if (OutScaleManager.nRAR.GetAreasResponseSend) { return Ok(OutScaleManager.nRAR.NoxRequestHandler(getAreas, RequestType.GETAREAS)); }
            }
        }
        OutScaleManager.LogRequest("This request was not sent, please create an instance and connected through the propper channels.");
        return Ok("This request was not sent, please create an instance and connected through the propper channels.");
    }
```

Comment: You *could* make it that instead of writing to a list and checking, that the call returns an [async enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8) and then asynchronously consume that enumerable and check each item for your uuid and cancel enumerating once you got the data you're looking for.

Comment: To me it sounds like the remote call should be changed to return a task that completes whenever it has added the object to its list. There is no such thing as "wait until object is in list", you either raise an event when objects are added, or use polling. But your question is not very clear, it might help if you could describe the API between your webapi and remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi i currently have a web api system where i send a command to a Machine at another location. Id like to wait for the response from the system to be available to send back to the requester. Currently when a request is made i generate a UUID and once data comes back from the other location it matches with that UUID and adds it to a response list.

Instead of using a list of available responses, structure your request/response system as a dictionary of outstanding requests. The dictionary would map GUIDs to `TaskCompletionSource<T>` where the `T` is the type of response data. For example, if your response data was `TResponse`, it could look like this:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, TaskCompletionSource<TResponse>> _requests = new();

public Task<TResponse> GetAreasAsync(GetAreas getAreas)
{
  var guid = OutScaleManager.nRAR.NoxRequestHandler(getAreas, RequestType.GETAREAS);
  TaskCompletionSource<TResponse> tcs = new();
  _requests.TryAdd(guid, tcs);
  return tcs.Task;
}

// Called when a GetAreas request completes:
public void SaveAreasResponse(Guid requestId, TResponse data)
{
  if (!_requests.TryRemove(requestId, out var tcs))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Response received for unknown request GUID.");
  tcs.TrySetResult(data);
}
```